# How to create a tar file from a jar file, Netbeans, ant

Tags: netbeans, ant, tar

Hi I have netbeans 6.7.1. My build.xml file creates a jar file. Now I want both jar and tar file. my tar file must be created from my jar file. SO how to create tar file from my jar file by making some changes in build.xml. I think it uses ant to create jar file.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious answer: use the Ant [`tar` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html). You will have to edit the Netbean `build.xml` file and invoke the `tar` task after the `jar` one.

I'm not a Netbean heavy user but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below. U have to provide full path of jar. Write the following inside  tag of build.xml file

```
<tar destfile="/root/NetBeansProjects/TextWandDesktop/store/TextWandDesktop.tar"
     basedir="/root/NetBeansProjects/TextWandDesktop/store/"/>
```

Thanks